# OSS Blank artifacts page

Tags: artifactory

So hello,
I'm hosting my own artifactory server(Open source license 7.4.3 rev 70403900 undefined, but cannot access the Artifacts page. If i click on it, the shown content is just blank.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQSrv.png).

I searched my JS Console and Browser Logs but did not see the problem

But, it's really strange bc other ppl can see the page. It's juse me who cannot. Any suggesions?

Comment: If this is happening only to you and other users can see this page, it might be related to your browser. Try cleaning up the browser cache and hard refreshing the artifacts page

Comment: I already tried this, sadly it's happening to all my browsers :c

Comment: Are you seeing any JavaScript errors in the browser console? or maybe a REST API call which is failing? are you an admin user or a regular one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by myself now.
I found out that this was an issue from my Antivirus software Kaspersky, which injected a JS into the site, which prevented it from loading. I had to manually turn the injection off (Advanced - network). I'm reporting this to Kaspersky and I'm hoping this can help you with similar issues if it's still not fixed.